# Why do we not have devices like inductors or capacitors to hold gravitational field?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, capacitance, gauss-law, inductance

I know that a capacitor can store electric field and an inductor can store magnetic field. So is there a way that gravitational field field can be stored in any such device. Also we do not have a law for gravitation as we do for electric field (Gauss's Law) and magnetic field (Ampere's Law)?

Comment: Does a heavy rock count?

Comment: For the law of gravitation part of the question, I think you're looking for [Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation).

Comment: Hydroelectric dams?

Comment: Actually we do have a [Gauss's law for gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity).

Answer (score 6):

It's not really true to say that a capacitor stores an electric field, or an inductor stores a magnetic field, though there are certainly fields associated with both. I think a better way of putting it is that both capacitors and inductors store electromagnetic energy.

In that case your question becomes:

> Why do we not have devices like inductors or capacitors to hold gravitational energy?

And the answer is that we do have such devices - lots of them. Whenever you lift an object you store gravitational energy, and you can get that energy back by dropping the object. For example this principle is used commercially to store electrical energy for use in power generation and it is known as [pumped-storage hydroelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity).